# Variable between two source files (class & global)

Tags: c++

Consider having one variable that is handled by one `.cpp` file, while other `.cpp` files use that variable's value for various purposes.

***When used with classes***

```
// header.h
class c {
public:
    static int f1();
    static int f2();
private:
    static int v;
};  

// first.cpp  
int c::v(0);

int c::f1() { return ++v; }  

// second.cpp
int c::f2() { return ++v; }  

// main.cpp
int main() {
    cout << c::f1() << endl;
    cout << c::f2() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
1
2
```

***When used in global scope***

```
// header.h
int f1();  
int f2();  
static int v = 0;  

// first.cpp  
int f1() { return ++v; }  

// second.cpp
int f2() { return ++v; }  

// main.cpp
int main() {
    cout << f1() << endl;
    cout << f2() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
1
1
```

How come when said variable is in a class, the output is what you expect and otherwise it is not? (I am aware that using `extern` in the second part would give the wanted result, the question is rather why `static` works in case with the class but not with the global scope?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static` has more than a single meaning in C++ (the language designers actually do this thing quite a lot, in order to reduce the number of reserved keywords).

- `static` in a class means that it is a variable shared by all instances of the class.
- `static` in a a compilation unit means that it cannot be addressed in a different compilation unit. In this case, you wrote `static` in the header; the preprocessor (via the ``#include`s) inserted it into compilable source files. In each source file including this header, it simply means that this is a  variable that is local to this compilation unit.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: each file gets its own copy of this variable? So, if OP where to put `f1()` and `f2()` in the same file, then he would actually get `1` and `2` as output? Moreover, if he didn't declare `v` as `static` then all the files would share this variable and again the output would be `1` and `2`?

Comment: @dingalapadum I completely agree with the first part. As to the second part, not quite - you might be right in principle, but in this case the linker will complain about the variable having multiple definitions.

Answer (score 1):

1. The keyword `static`, when used in a `class`, means the member of that class is shared by all it's instances. So every time `v` is incremented in `class c`, it returns a value greater than the previous value.
2. But when the keyword `static` is used in global space, has nothing to do with objects. `static` in global space means **ONLY** that variable `v` is accessible from within that `.cpp` file in which it is declared/defined and in those files in which it's file is `#include`d. And cannot be accessed from elsewhere.
3. `static` in OOP's is completely different from `static` in non-OOP's.